# ASPBoilerPlate - The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am having a .net MVC core application running on a AWS ECS linux fargate . There 2 cases are following :

1. MSSQL Database is hosted in same VPC as RDS : In this case everything is working fine. ECS (Container service) warming up and during that time backgroundjob of ABP is also running without issue. After that over all application is always responding without error.
2. MSSQL Database is hosted in different VPC inside an EC2 : The problem is coming here. ECS is warming up, starting but in log file of application showing below error. After application is also not responding with right data always. I cant say that database is not connecting as all, because ABPAuditLog table also capturing these error.

Error :
WARN  2023-03-24 14:11:44,639 [11   ] Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobManager  - System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.DbContextEfCoreTransactionStrategy.CreateDbContext[TDbContext](String connectionString, IDbContextResolver dbContextResolver) at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Uow.EfCoreUnitOfWork.GetOrCreateDbContext[TDbContext](Nullable`1 multiTenancySide, String name)
at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.get_Table() at Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Repositories.EfCoreRepositoryBase`3.GetAllIncluding(Expression`1[] propertySelectors) at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.IRepository`2_GetAll_3.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformSyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options)
at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
at Castle.Proxies.IRepository`2Proxy_1.GetAll() at Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobStore.GetWaitingJobsAsync(Int32 maxResultCount) at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.BackgroundJobStore_GetWaitingJobsAsync.InvokeMethodOnTarget() at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() at Abp.Domain.Uow.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.PerformAsyncUow(IInvocation invocation, UnitOfWorkOptions options) at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() at Castle.Proxies.BackgroundJobStoreProxy.GetWaitingJobsAsync(Int32 maxResultCount) at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException[TResult](Task`1 task) at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Nito.AsyncEx.Synchronous.TaskExtensions.WaitAndUnwrapException[TResult](Task`1 task) at Nito.AsyncEx.AsyncContext.Run[TResult](Func`1 action)
at Abp.BackgroundJobs.BackgroundJobManager.DoWork()

We have tried to increase dbcontext timesout from :
a) mention timeout in connection string
b) explicitly set timeout in constructor of DbContext

But no luck.